# Как в html таблице (table) сделать перенос строки с "слева направо" на "сверху вниз"?

Tags: css, table, выравнивание

Есть таблица характеристик, которая автоматически выводится на сайте после заполнения характеристик товара.

Сейчас вывод характеристик выглядит так:

```
Тип хар.1 | Тип хар.2
Тип хар.3 | Тип хар.4
Тип хар.5 | Тип хар.6
Тип хар.7
```

То есть ячейки идут с слева на право. Вот собственно код подобной таблицы: http://cssdeck.com/labs/mw6z7vi8

Мне же надо чтобы таблица выглядела так (строки сверху вниз):

```
Тип хар.1 | Тип хар.5
Тип хар.2 | Тип хар.6
Тип хар.3 | Тип хар.7
Тип хар.4
```

---

Пробовал с flex сделать, но он не растягивает ячейки по ширине, а также требует фиксированную высоту: http://cssdeck.com/labs/yqtm4rs0

Что можете посоветовать в данном случае?

Comment: Как это вообще можно понять? Дайте картинку как должно быть.

Comment: Извиняюсь, теперь должно быть понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Почти верное решение получилось. Но надо подобное сделать без использования height, так как строк может быть разное количество, да и высота строк тоже разная.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tbody {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  outline: 1px solid #a52a2a;
  height: 150px;
}

tr {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid #a52a2a;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table><tbody>
<tr><td>item1</td></tr>
<tr><td>item2</td></tr>
<tr><td>item3</td></tr>
<tr><td>item4</td></tr>
<tr><td>item5</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такое решение:

```css
table,
td {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
  background-color: pink;
}

div {
  background-color: olive;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>66</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Это разумеется шутка )) но что интересно визуально решает проблему. Только вот резмеры в контейнере остались нетрансформированными

Comment: Почти), но есть условие что html трогать нельзя. Тут все написано:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/mw6z7vi8

Comment: @ThomasJefferson так я его как раз и не трогал, `div` вставил для демонстрации. Мой пример будет работать для любой таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Остановился пока на таком варианте:

```css
@media (min-width:460px) {
table {
  column-count: 2;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  column-gap: 2em;
}
}

tr {
  outline: 1px solid #a52a2a;
}

td {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Тип</td><td>Акриловая1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Тип</td><td>Акриловая2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Тип</td><td>Акриловая3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Тип</td><td>Акриловая4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Тип</td><td>Акриловая5</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы работать с элементами таблицы как с блочными элементами их нужно переопределить с помощью `display`.
Пример с использованием `columns`:

```css
table {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  width: 100%;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-column-width: 50%;
  -moz-column-width: 50%;
  -moz-column-fill: balance;
  column-fill: balance;
  column-width: 50%;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  column-gap: 0;
  -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid black;
  -moz-column-rule: 1px solid black;
  column-rule: 1px solid black;
}

tr {
  display: block;
}

td {
  display: block;
  border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>item1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>item5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Код для "сложных таблиц"

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  table {
    border: 0;
  }
  table thead {
    display: none;
  }
  table tr {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  }
  table td {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
  }
  table td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  table td:before {
    content: attr(data-label);
    float: left;   
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Тип 1</th>
      <th>Тип 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td data-label="Тип 1">Акриловая 1</td>
      <td data-label="Тип 2">Акриловая 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Тип 1">Гуаш 1</td>
      <td data-label="Тип 2">Гуаш 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-label="Тип 1">Акварель 1</td>
      <td data-label="Тип 2">Акварель 2</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Я этот способ первым делом попробовал. С ним у меня таблица выглядит так: http://nimb.ws/AMlnp0

Это больше подойдет для простых таблиц. Код таблицы, которую выводит двиг вот: https://codepen.io/chadrex/pen/wpKjYe?editors=1100